# Split array string into another array

Tags: c#, arrays, split

I am using C# .NET 2005.

How can I split an array into another array with a separator of ^??

I have an array:

```
arrData[0]
```

which contains:

```
queency^sablan^21
```

how can I split this into:

```
arrData[0] = Queency
arrData[1] = Sablan
arrData[2] = 21
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a String value in your array, you can use the Split method.

```
var anotherArray = arrData[0].Split('^');
```

Answer (score 2):

How about this

```
arrData = arrData[0].Split('^');
```